# TargetInvocationException on Nhibernate QueryOver with JoinAlias

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

```
Product productAlias = null;
Session sessionAlias = null;
Slot slotAlias = null;
Price priceAlias = null;

var queryOver = session.QueryOver<Slot>(() => slotAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => slotAlias.Session, () => sessionAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => sessionAlias.Product, () => productAlias);

if (productGuid.HasValue)
{
    var productEntity = session.Query<Product>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Guid == productGuid.Value);
    queryOver = queryOver.Where(() => productAlias.Id == productEntity.Id);
}

if (onlyAvailable)
{
    queryOver = queryOver.Where(() => slotAlias.StartDate >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(productAlias.Duration));
}

queryOver.List();
```

When I run this query, I get TargetInvocationException. In the inner message it's a NullReferenceException at slotAlias.StartDate (Line 18, inside onlyAvailable if clause).

Is there something wrong with using aliases with if clauses and multiple Where clauses like this?

StackTrace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.FindValue(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessSimpleExpression(Expression left, Expression right, ExpressionType nodeType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessSimpleExpression(BinaryExpression be)
   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expression)
   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.NHibernate.IQueryOver<TRoot,TSubType>.Where(Expression`1 expression)
   at Fullseats.Database.Repositories.Repository.GetSlots(Int32 limit, Int32 offset, Nullable`1 operatorGuid, Nullable`1 productGuid, Nullable`1 from, Nullable`1 to, Boolean onlyAvailable) in C:\Users\erkin\Desktop\FullSeats\Fullseats.Api\Fullseats.Database\Repositories\Repository.cs:line 455
   at Fullseats.Server.Core.Services.ProductService.GetSlots(Guid productGuid, PaginationQuery paginationQuery) in C:\Users\erkin\Desktop\FullSeats\Fullseats.Api\Fullseats.Server\Core\Services\ProductService.cs:line 63
   at Fullseats.Server.Modules.ProductModule.GetSlotsForProduct(Object arg) in C:\Users\erkin\Desktop\FullSeats\Fullseats.Api\Fullseats.Server\Modules\ProductModule.cs:line 224
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Func`2 , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Nancy.Routing.Route.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3(Object parameters, CancellationToken context)
```

Comment: You should be able to do this-- Can you post the full exception text?

Comment: I wonder if it's related to [this JIRA issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3822)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker the problem happens when I use productAlias.Duration. If I just use any number in there it works.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't scroll far enough-- The issue is that the code inside of the expression `() => ...` is converted to SQL. NHibernate doesn't know what to do with the `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(productAlias.Duration)` bit. I will post a complete answer this afternoon

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Thank you. Btw, huge fan of your blog. Read it all. I think it can use some real life examples with complex quieries though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line:

```
queryOver.Where(
    () => slotAlias.StartDate >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(productAlias.Duration));
```

You're essentially mixing application-side logic with database-side logic. `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes` is executed *before* the query is sent to the database. That's why passing constant values, but not `productAlias.Duration`, worked.

Since you're not sending a predefined value as a parameter, you'll need to perform the date manipulation in the database.

Doing this might require a few steps, depending on your dialect. I'm going to assume SQL Server 2012.

1. Create a custom dialect with a function that defines an `addminutes` function:

   ```
   public class MyDialect : MsSql2012Dialect
   {
       public MyDialect()
       {
           this.RegisterFunction(
               "addminutes",
               new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.DateTimeOffset, "dateadd(n, ?1, ?2)"));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the newly registered function in your query:

   ```
   queryOver = queryOver.Where(
       Restrictions.GeProperty(
           Projections.Property(() => slotAlias.StartDate),
           Projections.SqlFunction(
               "addminutes",
               NHibernateUtil.DateTimeOffset,
               Projections.Property(() => productAlias.Duration),
               Projections.Constant(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow))))
   ```

This generates a SQL snippet that looks like this:

```
WHERE
    slotAlia_1.StartDate >= dateadd(minute, this_.Duration, '8/9/2016 2:22:48 AM +00:00');
```

The C# can be a bit hard to read, you could refactor out the `SqlFunction` part:

```
var addMinutesFunction = Projections.SqlFunction(
    "addMinutes",
    NHibernateUtil.DateTimeOffset,
    Projections.Property(() => productAlias.Duration),   
    Projections.Constant(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow))

queryOver = queryOver.Where(
    Restrictions.GeProperty(
        Projections.Property(() => slotAlias.StartDate), addMinutesFunction))
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer.
Instead of adding the time to DateTimeOffset.UtcNow adding it into slotAlias.StartDate did not work too. Since both slotAlias.StartDate and productAlias.Duration is database values shouldn't that work?

slotAlias.StartDate.AddMinutes(productAlias.Duration * -1) >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow

Comment: @erkinyldz: No, that won't work either, for similar reasons. Basically, NHibernate doesn't know how to translate the `AddMinutes` method on `DateTimeOffset` into a SQL expression, so you need to help it out by supplying a custom function.

Comment: Okay understood. Thank you for the help.